# Python: Date difference when one date is NAT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two `datetime` columns. One column has all the valid data, and the other column has missing date fields, hence there are some `NaT`. The problem at hand is that I need to take the difference between 2 columns, but whenever there is `NaT` value in the second column, the resultant column should have very large value say 100000. Here is the example:

Input data:

```
signup_date bgc_date
2016-01-02  NaT
2016-01-21  NaT
2016-01-11  2016-01-11
2016-01-29  2016-01-30
```

Expected Output

```
`signup_date    bgc_date           difference
 2016-01-02     NaT                  100000
 2016-01-21     NaT                  100000
 2016-01-11    2016-01-11             0
 2016-01-29    2016-01-30             1`
```

What I tried:

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
if pd.notnull(df2[i]['bgc_date']):
    df2[i]['diff'] = df2[i]['bgc_date']- df2[i]['signup_date']
else:
    df2[i]['diff']=10000
```

However, this is resulting into error. Can someone pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract the two columns and then fill missing values with a time delta:

```
(df.bgc_date - df.signup_date).fillna(pd.Timedelta(days=10000)).dt.days

#0    10000
#1    10000
#2        0
#3        1
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood`

Comment: Can you diagnose a little on which part throws the error? Make sure both of the columns `bgc_date` and `signup_date` are of date time data type. If not using `pd.to_datetime` to convert.